# How can I fix the Google Maps Tiles?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, maps, tiles

My problem is I have a google map with custom tiles and they are very slow to load (the tiles are grey for a while if I zoom out or in).

I searched a lot for an answer but found nothing.

Here is my website: https://ben-projects.de/Leitstelle/

Comment: Your site is doing like 100 requests per second to `https://ben-projects.de/Leitstelle/ajax/read.php` only to get a number. Check that; the requests are probably blocking the map rendering.

Comment: This was ist. Thanks